# Problem with async and fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I would like to return the value of a variable gotten from fetch outside of the fetch function. This is my current code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var playerName = "kada49";

async function fetchUUID() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${playerName}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

fetchUUID()
    .then(data => {
    let playerUUID = data.id;
    return playerUUID;
  });

var playerUUID = fetchUUID();
console.log(playerUUID);
```

as a response I get this in the console:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

WHat am I doing wrong?

Comment: ```var playerUUID = fetchUUID();``` is sycn. you should write it in async way.

Comment: put your logic inside the `.then` callback

Comment: `const playerUUID = (await fetchUUID()).id;`. Drop all the `.then()` stuff and spare yourself a few headaches :)